# Kivy label alignmen from python file

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to align-left a text label left column into a Kivy GridLayout,
to do that I tried to put the Label widget into a BoxLayout setting a static width on that but a strange behaviour happened, the label text seems to move left (out of the window) with longer text, here the example:

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        screen = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        self.update_data()

    def update_data(self, *args):
        events = [['soccer', '01/01/2020', '15:00', 'Borussia Dortmund', 'Borussia Monchengladbach', '1', 'William Hill', '2.55', 'Stanleybet' ,'3.40'],['soccer', '01/01/2020', '15:00', 'Roma', 'Lazio', '1', 'William Hill', '2.55', 'Stanleybet' ,'3.40'],['soccer', '01/01/2020', '15:00', 'Barcellona', 'Atletico De Madrid', '1', 'William Hill', '2.55', 'Stanleybet' ,'3.40']]
        for event in events:
            event_sport = str(event[0])
            event_date = str(event[1])
            event_time = str(event[2])
            home_contender = str(event[3])
            away_contender = str(event[4])
            event_sign = str(event[5])
            event_portal = str(event[6])
            event_portal_odds = event[7]
            event_portal2 = str(event[8])
            event_portal2_odds = str(event[9])
            event_data_content = BoxLayout(size_hint_x=None, width=180)
            event_data = Label(text=f'[color=#000000][size=14][b]{event_sport.upper()}[/b][/size]\n'
                                f'[size=13]{event_date} {event_time}[/size]\n'
                                f'{home_contender}\n'
                                f'{away_contender}[/color]',
                           size_hint_x=None,
                           width=150,
                           halign='left',
                           valign='top',
                           markup=True)
            event_data_content.add_widget(event_data)
            event_sign = Label(text=f'[color=000000][size=20]{event_sign}[/size][/color]',
                           halign='center',
                           valign='top',
                           markup=True)
            event_p = Label(text=f'[color=000000][i]{event_portal}[/i]\n'
                                  f'[size=13][b]{event_portal_odds}[/b][/color]',
                             halign="center",
                             valign="top",
                             markup=True)
            event_p2 = Label(text=f'[color=000000][i]{event_portal2}[/i]\n'
                                f'[size=13][b]{event_portal2_odds}[/b][/color]',
                           halign="center",
                           valign="top",
                           markup=True)
            self.root.ids.content.add_widget(event_data_content)
            self.root.ids.content.add_widget(event_sign)
            self.root.ids.content.add_widget(event_p)
            self.root.ids.content.add_widget(event_p2)


MyApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            MDGridLayout:
                id: content
                cols:4
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_default_height: '90dp'
                row_force_default: True
```

Here the result:

[image: Example result]

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your `halign` to work, you must set `text_size` (see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign)).

Also, your `width` of `150`causes wrapping of longer text. That's not an error, just a decision as to whether you want lines wrapped.

Try making the following changes to your code:

Create a custom `Label` for the `event_data`:

```
class EventLabel(Label):
    pass
```

Add a `kv` rule for the new `EventLabel`:

```
<EventLabel>:
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200             # the previous width of 150 caused text wrapping
    text_size: self.size   # this is needed to allow halign/valign to operate
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'top'
    markup: True
```

Use the new `EventLabel` in your code:

```
        event_data = EventLabel(text=f'[color=#000000][size=14][b]{event_sport.upper()}[/b][/size]\n'
                            f'[size=13]{event_date} {event_time}[/size]\n'
                            f'{home_contender}\n'
                            f'{away_contender}[/color]')
```

Comment: Tnx John! All clear and works like a charm ;)